# Прямая или косвенная речь

Tags: пунктуация

Кто-нибудь подскажет, правильно ли здесь оформлено высказывание:
Более того, я спросила свою невестку, вузовского преподавателя, как она оценивает новую двухуровневую систему. Положительно, ответила она, поскольку не надо тянуть слабых студентов еще два года.

Answer (score 1):

"Положительно, -  ответила она. - Поскольку не надо тянуть слабых студентов еще два года".

Comment: Т.е. здесь прямая речь?.. Ну или тогда:
"Положительно, - ответила она, - поскольку не надо тянуть слабых студентов еще два года".

Comment: Можно и так.

Comment: Интересно, что "ответила она" не употребляется в функции вводного предложения, а "заметила она" - употребляется. Если бы было "заметила она", оформлялось бы как косвенная речь.